# Why ask Billy for help instead of Castiel in S12E09: First Blood?

Tags: plot-explanation, supernatural

In Supernatural S12E09, Why did Sam and Dean ask for Billy's help instead of Castiel? In the past praying to Castiel worked, what has changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, the fact that Cas has damaged wings (if you remember, God did not fix that before leaving) means he can't move as freely as he used to and can't get inside the facility. So praying to him is useless.